# Get an object in Grid by rows and column c#

Tags: c#, object, grid, win-universal-app

I have a myGrid that include a Image and Rectangle Control in Every blocks.

How can i get Image Object form myGrid with rows and columns ?

Something like this:

```
Image myImage=(Image)Grid.GetObject(myGrid,rows,columns);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach(var child in myGrid.Childrens)
{
    int row = Grid.GetRow(child);
    int col = Grid.GetColumn(child);
}
```

Thanks,